# Unable to restore SQL database from Backup

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, restore, database-restore

I am trying to restore a SQL database from a backup created however am getting the following error: "Failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason 15105

I have selected the option "From database" under "Specify the source and location of backup sets to restore"

Below are my settings for the restoration.

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the error I am receiving.

[image]

By the way this is SQL server 2008.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the first part - "Cannot Open Backup Device". Thats your error. Probably the file doesnt exist.

You are asking the server to restore from the last time it was backed up, but the database has no knowledge of whether someone has then moved that backup file somewhere else.

If you click the "From Device" option then you can locate the backup file yourself, and restore from that.